# Android x86_64 and x86 emulator crash on AlertDialog.onClick event

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm testing an Android app in x86_64 and x86 emulator and it crash (Android emulator closed unexpectedly) after select an item from a AlertDialog that shows a list. AlertDialog is called from onOptionsItemSelected overrided method in class that extends from AppCompatActivity.

Some code:

```
public class ListViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private static final String TAG = "android-user-interface";

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
      return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Item de menu seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      builder.setTitle("titulo")
              .setItems(new String[]{"uno", "dos", "tres"}, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      //fails before this
                  }
              });
      AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
      alertDialog.show();
      //return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      return true;
  }
  //...
}
```

In crash windows I got

```
Operating system: Windows NT
                  10.0.10586 
CPU: amd64
     family 6 model 60 stepping 3
     8 CPUs

Crash reason:  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_READ
Crash address: 0x18
Assertion: Unknown assertion type 0x00000000
Process uptime: not available
... more info
```

Some ideas / information about this issue?

Comment: is this working well in other devices ?

Comment: Yes, it is working in other android emulators based on arm

Comment: Same problem here. OS: Arch Linux x64, Emulator: x86_64 API 24.

Comment: A workaround is set the Graphics setting to "Software - GLES 2.0". 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220919#c8

Comment: I have tested the code in Android Nougat x86_64 / x86 emulator and it fails. But in Android Marshmallow x86_64 emulator it works fine

Comment: facing same issue while showing alertDialogue any help?