# Android AVD crash on start on Intel chipset with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_READ

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Only a few seconds after launching the AVD, the emulator says that the OPENGL graphics driver **crashed**,Showing details reveal the following.

```
Operating system: Windows NT
                  6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
CPU: amd64
     family 6 model 58 stepping 9
     4 CPUs

Crash reason:  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_READ
Crash address: 0x18
Assertion: Unknown assertion type 0x00000000
Process uptime: 2 seconds

Thread 0 (crashed)
 0  ig7icd64.dll + 0x173f8a
...
```

It seems that it has something to do with the intel graphics driver ig7icd64.dll however unable to find a fix.

So far following **attempts** have been **unsuccessful**

- Updating the intel graphics driver, the latest version has the issue, trying an older version seems impossible without a reinstall of windows.
- Have tried different target levels of android SDK , different CPU types for AVD, recreating AVDs from scratch, nothing seems to change the error.
- Enabling software rendering / disabling it does not change the error even.
- Re-installing everything also did not help.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893311/android-x86-64-and-x86-emulator-crash-on-alertdialog-onclick-event)

Comment: Have you checked to see if there any updates within the SDK Manager. It might also be worth deleting the AVD and re-create it and see if that helps

Comment: Yes, deleted the AVD, the CPU ABI images and any data i could find related to the avd before installing again, no luck.

Comment: facing same emulator crash problem while showing alertDialogue ..Any help??

Answer (score 4):

You Just need To click on AVD Manager Wipeout user data then click on the pen to Edit Your Device and Change Graphic Setting to Software. That resolved my problem.

Comment: That caused my M2 chip to overheat for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

After a hard time with a lot of hit and trials, I was finally able to solve the problem by copying over an older version of **ig7icd64.dll** in `c:\windows\system32` while I had the latest driver installed already . (I believe an uninstall and reinstall of graphics driver to the older version will also work).

The version working for me is

`10.18.10.4276`

The version that gave me all sorts of problems was the latest one :

`10.18.10.4425`

**Also**

need to use software rendering , hardware rendering still crashes as the graphics card does not support that

Comment: Something similar worked for me. Windows said the drivers were all up to date. But I replaced ig75icd64.dll with the newest version, from dllme.com, and that fixed the problem. The next problem was the virtual device taking too long to load, which I fixed by following https://stackoverflow.com/a/51055375/

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error which was EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_READ.

This started to occur consistently when I updated my Emulator SDK version on Android SDK Manager. After that, I couldn't launch any emulator on any API level (always crashed).

So the solution for me was installing the older version of Emulator SDK, I believe I was downgrading from 33.1.2 to 31.3.12.

Just follow this [official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator) on how to downgrade your emulator version

Answer (score 0):

just uninstall Emulator SDK and reinstall it.
Go to tools -> SDK manager -> SDK tools