# Android Studio Virtual Device stuck on G screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Been stuck on this for so long, started a new project basic activity app on Android Studio, made a virtual device, but whenever i start it it used to just go to a 
black screen. Then i wiped memory and now its stuck on a screen with the google G logo with a little loading bar below it. Dosent seem to be moving. Tried increasing heap memory of the device like some solutions suggested, but that option was greyed out for me. Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This used to happen in my previous laptop. There can be two possibilities for this:-

1. System has less RAM i.e. less than 8 GB, in this case, try lowering the specs of the emulator by lowering the Resolution. (This was my case and it solved my problem)
2. The Emulator is heavy on the system which means it will run very slow, give it some time (like half an hour or so) since you have wiped out the memory, it's a fresh start, the first start will take time but subsequent boot up should be fast. (Example:- I recently emulated the specs of Google Pixel it took nearly 25 minutes just for initial boot and yes, it faced the similar problem as you described, but after that, it is running fine)

What I suggest is

- Try changing the specs of the emulator.
- If it doesn't boot, **I suggest using a physical Android device** (by enabling USB debugging)

It would help if you kindly share the exact specs of your system mainly Processor and RAM.

I hope this answer helps.

**Edit**
Try changing the emulator configurations to different settings like lowering the resolution, it might be possible you are using an HD device with 1080p resolution try changing it to 720p and then reboot the device.

Comment: Processor: Intel(r) Core(TM) i7-7500 CPU @ 2.70 GHz 2.90GHz
Installed RAM: 8 GB

Comment: The System specs are looking good, Have you tried changing the emulator configurations to different settings like lowering the resolution, it might be possible you are using an HD device with 1080p resolution try changing it to 720p and then reboot the device.

Comment: yeah i just got a real device and im testing it on it, seems there is no need to emulate a device a device if you have a real one?

Comment: Yes, it is better to use a real device because it does not hamper the performance of the system. I am happy to know that your issue is resolved, kindly mark this answer as "accepted" if it helped you. Best of luck for Android Development.

Comment: Changing resolution worked instantly, didnt know high res was so heavy on system

Comment: @UtsavGupta I am glad it helped

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on your question since I have a low reputation so I have to respond through an answer. What API level are you using for the virtual device? Could you try to change it to another through the Android Virtual Device Manager? Are you able to create any other types of virtual devices? Lastly, you should check if any updates are available. Press Ctrl+Shift+A (or Command+Shift+A for Mac) and search "Android SDK". Then look under the Status tab for both the SDK Platforms and SDK Tools tabs for updates.

Answer (score 1):

Wipe data of your emulator. Open AVD Manager AVD(Tools->AVD Manager) click on the small arrow for desired emulator then click on "Wipe data".

Source:https://stackoverflow.com/a/45358524/8076629

Answer (score 0):

I think Your machine has low configurations of Processor and Memory, that's why it is not able to Handel both Android Studio and Emulator at the same time.